# How does VF decide when to instantiate a new instance for a controller

Tags: visualforce

I am following the book Visualforce Developer's Guide. There is one thing I am not quite clear with: when multiple VF pages are using one single controller - like in a wizard, how do VF decide when to create a new controller class instance and when will it use a previous one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to **visualforce guide > pageReference > setRedirect** https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm:

> If `setRedirect(false)`, the redirect is a **server-side forward** that **preserves the view state** if and only if the target page uses the same controller and contains the proper subset of extensions used by the source page.

In other words, if you want the controller to be reinstantiated (and hence the constructor reinvoked), in the pageReference method, use `pgRef.setRedirect(true)`. The next page is loaded with the whole controller reinstantiated via its constructor.

But, if you don't want the controller class to be reinstantiated, use `pgRef.setRedirect(false)`. the next page is loaded without re-construction.