# Error in wrapper class.I guess!

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class

I have created a page which shows shows some record with checkboxes.If i click on checkbox and select some field and click on button "show account on same page"..selected record are displaye on same page on different table..but when i click on "show record on different page"..it doesnot work..can someone help me

My vf page:-

```
<apex:page controller="AccountSelectClassController" sidebar="false">

    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Show Selected Accounts same page" action="{!processSelected}" rerender="table2"/>
                <apex:commandButton value="Show Selected Accounts" action="{!createpdf}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

            <apex:pageblockSection title="All Accounts" collapsible="false" columns="2">

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!wrapAccountList}" var="accWrap" id="table" title="All Accounts">
                    <apex:column >

                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!accWrap.selected}" id="inputId"/>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!accWrap.acc.Name}" />

                </apex:pageBlockTable>
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedAccounts}" var="c" id="table2" title="Selected Accounts">
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" headerValue="Account Name"/>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>


            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

My controller:-

```
public class AccountSelectClassController{

    //Our collection of the class/wrapper objects wrapAccount
    public List<wrapAccount> wrapAccountList {get; set;}
    public List<Account> selectedAccounts{get;set;}

    public AccountSelectClassController(){
        if(wrapAccountList == null) {
            wrapAccountList = new List<wrapAccount>();
            for(Account a: [select Id, Name,BillingState, Website, Phone from Account limit 3]) {
                // As each Account is processed we create a new wrapAccount object and add it to the wrapAccountList
                wrapAccountList.add(new wrapAccount(a));
            }
        }
    }

    public void processSelected() {
    selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();

        for(wrapAccount wrapAccountObj : wrapAccountList) {
            if(wrapAccountObj.selected == true) {
                selectedAccounts.add(wrapAccountObj.acc);
            }
        }
    }

    // This is our wrapper/container class. In this example a wrapper class contains both the standard salesforce object Account and a Boolean value
    public class wrapAccount {
        public Account acc {get; set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;}

        public wrapAccount(Account a) {
            acc = a;
            selected = false;
        }
    }

    public pagereference createpdf()
    {

    pagereference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/generateselectedrecord');
    selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();

        for(wrapAccount wrapAccountObj : wrapAccountList) {
            if(wrapAccountObj.selected == true) {
                selectedAccounts.add(wrapAccountObj.acc);
            }
        }
    redirect.setRedirect(true);
    return redirect;
}
}
```

new page for "show account on different page" button:

```
<apex:page controller="AccountSelectClassController" sidebar="false">

    <apex:form >    
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection >        
     <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!selectedAccounts}" var="c" id="table2" title="Selected Accounts">
                    <apex:column value="{!c.Name}" headerValue="Account Name"/>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>

            </apex:pageblockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not work". Does it give any error then please mention. If no error then what happens?

Comment: values are not displayedon new page

Comment: have you tried redirect.setRedirect(false);

Comment: Thanks you it does work,...but just changing the value to false..i mean i searched on net..i am not understanding what was the errror actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Apex Method**

```
public pagereference createpdf()
    {

    pagereference redirect = new PageReference('/apex/generateselectedrecord');
    selectedAccounts = new List<Account>();

        for(wrapAccount wrapAccountObj : wrapAccountList) {
            if(wrapAccountObj.selected == true) {
                selectedAccounts.add(wrapAccountObj.acc);
            }
        }
    redirect.setRedirect(false);
    return redirect;
}
```

Please review below link for understanding,

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_System_PageReference_setRedirect.htm

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are talking about clicking the button "Show Selected Accounts" that your code contains, I posted a solution to the problem in my answer to [need a customised pdf](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78529/need-a-customised-pdf).

When you redirect to a page, the new page creates a new instance of the controller class so any values you require must be passed to that new instance. Any non-persisted work done in the controller that did the redirect is lost.

See [How does VF decide when to instantiate a new instance for a controller](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32252/how-does-vf-decide-when-to-instantiate-a-new-instance-for-a-controller) for some background.